# Ruby (bundle install, bundle update) FAILS can't install gems http_parser.rb, eventmachine

Tags: ruby, drupal, makefile, gruntjs, rubygems

**I am using grunt to run scss file to build on a existing project in drupal. project using grunt to generate css files. These are the errors comming on my** **OS: windows-10 machine 64-bit.**

I have tried in every possible way to run the grunt command and failed in every possible situation, I'm very new to usage of grunt and ruby. Can post additional details if asked for. I have other projects too where grunt works perfectly fine. But I'm stuck with this **make file** and **gem native extensions**

**My whole environment and configuration settings**

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.13
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.2 (2017-09-14 patchlevel 198) [x64-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby24-x64/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/user/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x64-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
     - C:/Users/user/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\Users\user\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
     - C:\Users\user\bin
     - C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client
     - C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client
     - C:\windows\system32
     - C:\windows
     - C:\windows\System32\Wbem
     - C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
     - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
     - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\win64
     - C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin
     - C:\Program Files\PuTTY
     - C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
     - C:\Program Files\nodejs
     - C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
     - C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
     - C:\Ruby24-x64\bin
     - C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
     - C:\php5
     - C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
     - C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm
     - C:\mysys64\mingw64\bin
     - C:\mysys64\usr\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl
     - C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
```

**BUNDLE INSTALL ERROR**

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Resolving dependencies...
RubyGems 1.8.29 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to RubyGems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Using addressable 2.3.8
Using sass 3.4.16
Using sassy-maps 0.4.0
Using breakpoint 2.5.0
Using bundler 1.16.0.pre.2
Using chunky_png 1.3.4
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using compass-core 1.0.3
Using compass-import-once 1.0.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.5
Using ffi 1.9.10 (x64-mingw32)
Using rb-inotify 0.9.5
Using compass 1.0.3
Using compass-normalize 1.5
Using compass-rgbapng 0.2.1
Using compass-validator 3.0.1
Using css_parser 1.3.6
Fetching eventmachine 1.0.7
Installing eventmachine 1.0.7 with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
extension.

        C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_fdset_t in ruby/intern.h... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_enable_interrupt()... no
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for -lkernel32... yes
checking for -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for -lgdi32... yes
checking for clock_gettime()... yes
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW in time.h... no
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs':
Could not find make (>= 0.a) amongst [addressable-2.5.2, addressable-2.3.8,
breakpoint-2.7.1, breakpoint-2.5.0, chunky_png-1.3.8, chunky_png-1.3.4,
coderay-1.1.2, coderay-1.1.0, compass-1.0.3, compass-core-1.0.3,
compass-import-once-1.0.5, compass-normalize-1.5, compass-rgbapng-0.2.1,
compass-validator-3.0.1, css_parser-1.6.0, css_parser-1.3.6,
eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32, ffi-1.9.18-x64-mingw32, ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32,
multi_json-1.12.2, multi_json-1.11.2, public_suffix-3.0.0, rb-fsevent-0.10.2,
rb-fsevent-0.9.5, rb-inotify-0.9.10, rb-inotify-0.9.5, sass-3.4.25, sass-3.4.16,
sassy-maps-0.4.0] (Gem::LoadError)
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in
`to_spec'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:25:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Users/user/git/project/_vendor/ruby/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7
for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Users/user/git/project/_vendor/ruby/2.4.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing eventmachine (1.0.7), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '1.0.7'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  guard-livereload was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
    em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.1, which depends on
      eventmachine
```

**BUNDLE UPDATE ERROR**

```
$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Resolving dependencies....
RubyGems 1.8.29 is not threadsafe, so your gems will be installed one at a time. Upgrade to RubyGems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
Using public_suffix 3.0.0
Using addressable 2.5.2 (was 2.3.8)
Using sass 3.4.25 (was 3.4.16)
Using sassy-maps 0.4.0
Using breakpoint 2.7.1 (was 2.5.0)
Using bundler 1.16.0.pre.2
Using chunky_png 1.3.8 (was 1.3.4)
Using coderay 1.1.2 (was 1.1.0)
Using multi_json 1.12.2 (was 1.11.2)
Using compass-core 1.0.3
Using compass-import-once 1.0.5
Using rb-fsevent 0.10.2 (was 0.9.5)
Using ffi 1.9.18 (x64-mingw32) (was 1.9.10)
Using rb-inotify 0.9.10 (was 0.9.5)
Using compass 1.0.3
Using compass-normalize 1.5
Using compass-rgbapng 0.2.1
Using compass-validator 3.0.1
Using css_parser 1.6.0 (was 1.3.6)
Using eventmachine 1.2.5 (x64-mingw32) (was 1.0.7)
Fetching http_parser.rb 0.6.0
Installing http_parser.rb 0.6.0 with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
extension.

        C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs':
Could not find make (>= 0.a) amongst [addressable-2.5.2, addressable-2.3.8,
breakpoint-2.7.1, breakpoint-2.5.0, chunky_png-1.3.8, chunky_png-1.3.4,
coderay-1.1.2, coderay-1.1.0, compass-1.0.3, compass-core-1.0.3,
compass-import-once-1.0.5, compass-normalize-1.5, compass-rgbapng-0.2.1,
compass-validator-3.0.1, css_parser-1.6.0, css_parser-1.3.6,
eventmachine-1.2.5-x64-mingw32, ffi-1.9.18-x64-mingw32, ffi-1.9.10-x64-mingw32,
multi_json-1.12.2, multi_json-1.11.2, public_suffix-3.0.0, rb-fsevent-0.10.2,
rb-fsevent-0.9.5, rb-inotify-0.9.10, rb-inotify-0.9.5, sass-3.4.25, sass-3.4.16,
sassy-maps-0.4.0] (Gem::LoadError)
from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in
`to_spec'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:25:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Users/user/git/project/_vendor/ruby/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0
for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Users/user/git/project/_vendor/ruby/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing http_parser.rb (0.6.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install http_parser.rb -v '0.6.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  guard-livereload was resolved to 2.5.2, which depends on
    em-websocket was resolved to 0.5.1, which depends on
      http_parser.rb
```

**GRUNT ERROR**

```
$ grunt
Running "uglify:dist" (uglify) task
>> 1 file created 2.65 kB → 1.3 kB

Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:276:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'json x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:244:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:244:in `verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:44:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:22:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:258:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:238:in `specs_for'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:227:in `requested_specs'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:110:in `block in definition_method'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:22:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0.pre.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**Installing http_parser.rb ERROR**

```
$gem install http_parser.rb 0.6.0 --platform=ruby --verbose
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=http_parser.rb
200 OK
Getting SRV record failed: DNS result has no information for _rubygems._tcp.api.rubygems.org
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/.gitignore
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/.gitmodules
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/Gemfile
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/Gemfile.lock
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/LICENSE-MIT
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/README.md
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/Rakefile
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/bench/standalone.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/bench/thin.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/.gitignore
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/RubyHttpParserService.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/ext_help.h
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/extconf.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/org/ruby_http_parser/RubyHttpParser.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/ruby_http_parser.c
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/.gitkeep
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/http_parser.rb.gemspec
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/lib/http/parser.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/lib/http_parser.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/spec/parser_spec.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/spec/spec_helper.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/spec/support/requests.json
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/spec/support/responses.json
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/tasks/compile.rake
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/tasks/fixtures.rake
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/tasks/spec.rake
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/tasks/submodules.rake
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/AUTHORS
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/CONTRIBUTIONS
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/http_parser.c
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/http_parser.gyp
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/http_parser.h
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/LICENSE-MIT
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/Makefile
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/README.md
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser/test.c
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/AUTHORS
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/build.xml
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/ext/primitives.jar
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/http_parser.c
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/http_parser.gyp
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/http_parser.h
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/LICENSE-MIT
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/Makefile
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/README.md
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/Http-parser.java.iml
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/FieldData.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/HTTPCallback.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/HTTPDataCallback.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/HTTPErrorCallback.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/HTTPException.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/HTTPMethod.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/HTTPParser.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/HTTPParserUrl.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/lolevel/HTTPCallback.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/lolevel/HTTPDataCallback.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/lolevel/HTTPErrorCallback.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/lolevel/HTTPParser.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/lolevel/ParserSettings.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/ParserSettings.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/ParserType.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/impl/http_parser/Util.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/Message.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/ParseUrl.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/Requests.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/Responses.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/Test.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/TestHeaderOverflowError.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/TestLoaderNG.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/TestNoOverflowLongBody.javacreating Makefile
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:23:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:23:in `<main>'
ERROR:  Error installing http_parser.rb:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
Building has failed. See above output for more information on the failure.
make failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.4.0/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/gem_make.out
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '0.6.0' (>= 0) in any repository

C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/UnitTest.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/Upgrade.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/Url.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/Util.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/src/test/http_parser/lolevel/WrongContentLength.java
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/test.c
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/tests.dumped
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/tests.utf8
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/TODO
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/tools/byte_constants.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/tools/const_char.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/tools/lowcase.rb
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser/vendor/http-parser-java/tools/parse_tests.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
C:/Ruby24-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170926-7872-1urktzr.rb extconf.rb
current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/http_parser.rb-0.6.0/ext/ruby_http_parser
make "DESTDIR="
HEAD https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=0.6.0
200 OK
GET https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
```

**GEM and Ruby versions**

```
$ gem -v
2.6.13

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Now works after running** `$gem uninstall make` *which is where the error is occuring after this ran* `$bundle install` now got another problem with `yajl-ruby (1.2.1)` 
for this what I have done is updated to the latest gem.

```
$gem install yajl-ruby
```

from https://rubygems.org/gems/yajl-ruby/versions/1.3.0 copy the install clipboard paste in your project folder.
Now after this I have updated the version in gemfile.lock
and again run `$bundle install` this worked for me.
after this `$grunt`
*hope this helps someone*